# C# error handling Question

Tags: c#, exception, try-catch

In my code, I have a loop and inside a `try` `catch`. When an error is encountered, `catch` block works, should log the error and send an email to inform about the error message.

Now I want it to do this and go back to the loop to continue the treatement.

If I have to loop through 100 records, and an error is detected in the 51st record, then the `catch` should log it, email it, and come back to continue with the 52nd record (kind of RESUME NEXT in VBS).

How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> in my code I have a loop and inside a try catch,

If your try-catch block is inside your loop, then you should be fine:

```
for ( ... )
{
    try
    {
        ...
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

If its outside your for loop, then just move it inside :)

Answer (score 9):

Catch the exception in the loop (not outside the loop). Then it would just continue with the loop.

Comment: aggreed that would be the simplest way

Comment: What if he has a logic after the try catch statement still inside the loop ??

Comment: @Akram Shahda, what would be wrong with him just including that logic in the try? Even if that section of code won't throw an error, he needs it in the try so that it'll skip that logic.

Comment: @Corey Ogburn: It is recommended to place only logic that might throw exceptions inside the `try{} catch{}` statement. Still he can do whatever he need.

Answer (score 3):

```
foreach(var record in records)
{
   try
   {
       processRecord(record);
   }
   catch(*Exception that you are interested in*)
   {
       // log exception
       // spawn new backgroundworker to send email about exception
   }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

place the following structure within your loop:

```
//While (Looping)
//{    

    try
    {
        // write your logic here ..

    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        // log exception && send mail

        continue;
    }


    // more logic could be here ..

//}
```

Comment: Thanks alot guys, after 5 hours coding non stop, one start saying posting 6u!! sh!t :)) i was just confused, all solutions worked just fine thanks

Comment: @evdotnet: We are glad to help. However, would you thank us by accepting the most appropriate answer ..